# Powershell: Foreach cmdlet overwriting dataset with results of last item

Tags: powershell, foreach, overwrite

My output, will always contain the information from the second item (database), it seems that it is overwriting any values returned for the initial items? I can change the order of the items in to prove this. Please help...

```
    $databaselist = Get-Content D:\AdvancedDB\Server2.txt 
    $servername = get-content D:\AdvancedDB\Server.txt
    $dataSource = $servername
    $myuserID = 'userid'
    $mypassword = 'password'


    $DatabaseIndexInfo =
    "SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema',
    dbtables.[name] as 'Table',
    dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    indexstats.page_count
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
    INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
    WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
    ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc"

    $connectionDetails = "Provider=sqloledb; " + "Server=$dataSource; " + "Database=$database; " +  
    "User 
    ID=$myuserID; " + " Password=$mypassword; "


    $frag16 = @()

    foreach ($database in $databaselist) {


   ##Connect to the data source using the connection details and T-SQL command we provided above, and 
    open the connection
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionDetails
    $command16 = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand $DatabaseIndexInfo,$connection
    $connection.Open()


##Get the results of our command into a DataSet object, and close the connection
   $dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command16
   $dataSet16 = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
   $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet16) 
   $connection.Close()

     }


    $frag16 += $dataset16.Tables | Out-File 'd:\advanceddb\test5.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move your connection details within the foreach loop. If you need to work with different databases, then you need to update your connection string as well.

```
foreach ($database in $databaselist) {
    $connectionDetails = "Provider=sqloledb; " + "Server=$dataSource; " + "Database=$database; " +  
    "User ID=$myuserID; " + " Password=$mypassword; "
    ...
```

Since connectionDetails is not updated within your loop, you keep seeing the same data.

Comment: Jawad, thank you, that has worked as expected. I had this working before and I could not figure what I had moved around to have caused the issue. Much appreciated.